# Proc Report in SAS ODS WORD file is removing borders

Tags: sas

[image: Output I am getting Now]In my SAS Code, I am trying to Report a table into a Word file using SAS ODS statement. And I am using the Company's standard styles. When the job runs, I can see the borders of Proc report output table in the output window. But these are gone in the Word file. Please see code below:

```
    ods word file="&outfolder\Tabulations and graphs for &current_month. &current_year. report.docx" style=custom_style; 
    options orientation=landscape nodate nonumber center topmargin=0.1in bottommargin=0.15in rightmargin=0.2in leftmargin=0.2in papersize=letter;

    ods escapechar="^";
    ods graphics on/ outputfmt=png height = 6.75in;

    %let footnote_style = ^S = {just=l font_size=7pt font_weight = light};

    proc report data=out.sample nowd spanrows split="$" ;
    /*There are multiple define statements here*/
    run;
    ods word close;
```

There is a long list of customized styles, So I can't remove it.

Also, If I use ODS PDF then the borders appear in PDF but somehownot in docx file.

Custom Style code:

```
    proc template;                                                                
        define style Styles.custom_styles;
        style fonts/ 
            'TitleFont2'=("Arial",12pt,bold) 
            'TitleFont'=("Arial",12pt,bold)    
            'headingFont'=("Arial",10pt,bold)       
            'docFont'=("Arial",10pt)            
            'footFont'=("Arial",8pt) 
            'StrongFont'=("Arial",14pt,bold)        
            'EmphasisFont'=("Arial",14pt,italic)    
            'FixedEmphasisFont'=("<monospace>, Courier, monospace",10pt,italic)   
            'FixedStrongFont'=("<monospace>, Courier, monospace",10pt,bold)       
            'FixedHeadingFont'=("<monospace>, Courier, monospace",10pt)           
            'BatchFixedFont'=("<monospace>, Courier, monospace",10pt)                                                                   
            'FixedFont'=("<monospace>, Courier, monospace",10pt)                  
            'headingEmphasisFont'=("Arial",14pt,bold italic);
        style GraphFonts/                                                      
            'GraphDataFont'=("Arial",7pt)               
            'GraphValueFont'=("Arial",9pt)              
            'GraphLabel2Font'=("Arial",10pt)            
            'GraphLabelFont'=("Arial",10pt)        
            'GraphFootnoteFont'=("Arial",8pt)     
            'GraphTitleFont'=("Arial",12pt,bold)        
            'GraphTitle1Font'=("Arial",12pt,bold)       
            'GraphAnnoFont'=("Arial",8pt)            
            'GraphUnicodeFont'=("<MTsans-serif-unicode>",9pt);
        style color_list "Colors used in the default style"/                                 
            'bgA'=cxffffff    
            'bgA1'=cx005293                                                  
            'bgb1'=cxe05206                                                 
            'fgA'=cxffffff                                                    
            'fgB1'=cx000000                                                 
            'grey'=cxCCCCCC                                                
            'fgD1'=cx005293  
     
            'blue1'=cx005293                                                  
            'orange1'=cxe05206  
            'red1'=cxd52b1e 
            'green2'=cx007582 
            'grey2'=cx6f7c7d  
            'moss2'=cx476822  
            'yellow2'=cxf6a800 
            'black2'=cx31261d 
            'blue2'=cx009cde 
            'black'=cx000000;                                                 
        style colors "Abstract colors used in the default style"/                        
            'headerfg'=color_list('bgA')                                     
            'headerbg'=color_list('bgA1')                                      
            'tablebg'=cxcccccc                                                 
            'headerfgemph'=color_list('bgA')                                   
            'headerbgemph'=color_list('bgA1')                                  
            'headerfgstrong'=color_list('bgA')                                 
            'headerbgstrong'=color_list('bgA1')                                
            'datafgemph'=color_list('fgB1')                                    
            'databgemph'=color_list('bgA')                                     
            'datafgstrong'=color_list('fgB1')                                  
            'databgstrong'=color_list('bgA')                                   
            'datafg'=color_list('fgB1')                                        
            'databg'=color_list('bgA')                                         
            'batchfg'=color_list('blue1')                                        
            'batchbg'=color_list('bgA')                                        
            'tableborder'=color_list('fgD1')                                   
            'notefg'=color_list('fgB1')                                         
            'notebg'=color_list('bgA')                                         
            'bylinefg'=color_list('blue1')                                       
            'bylinebg'=color_list('bgA')                                       
            'captionfg'=color_list('fgB1')                                      
            'captionbg'=color_list('bgA')                                      
            'proctitlefg'=color_list('fgB1')                                    
            'proctitlebg'=color_list('bgA')                                    
            'titlefg'=color_list('fgB1')                                        
            'titlebg'=color_list('bgA')                                        
            'systitlefg'=color_list('fgB1')                                     
            'systitlebg'=color_list('bgA')                                     
            'contentfg'=color_list('fgB1')                                      
            'contentbg'=color_list('bgA')                                      
            'docfg'=color_list('fgB1')                                          
            'docbg'=color_list('bgA');
        style graphcolors/
            'gdata1'=color_list('blue1') 'gcdata1'=color_list('blue1')
            'gdata2'=color_list('orange1') 'gcdata2'=color_list('orange1') 
            'gdata3'=color_list('red1') 'gcdata3'=color_list('red1') 
            'gdata4'=color_list('green2') 'gcdata4'=color_list('green2') 
            'gdata5'=color_list('grey2') 'gcdata5'=color_list('grey2') 
            'gdata6'=color_list('moss2') 'gcdata6'=color_list('moss2') 
            'gdata7'=color_list('yellow2') 'gcdata7'=color_list('yellow2') 
            'gdata8'=color_list('black2') 'gcdata8'=color_list('black2') 
            'gdata9'=color_list('blue2') 'gcdata9'=color_list('blue2') 
            'gcdata12'=cxF7AC4E 'gdata12'=cxF7AC4E 
            'gcdata11'=cxB38EF3 'gdata11'=cxB38EF3
            'gcdata10'=cx47A82A 'gdata10'=cx47A82A 
            'gcmiss'=cx979797                                                  
            'gmiss'=cxc3c3c2                                                   
            'gablock'=colors('docbg')                                          
            'gblock'=colors('docbg')                                           
            'gcclipping'=cxDC531F                                              
            'gclipping'=cxE7774F                                               
            'gcstars'=cx000000                                                 
            'gstars'=cxB9CFE7                                                  
            'gcruntest'=cxBF4D4D                                               
            'gruntest'=cxCAE3FF                                                
            'gccontrollim'=cxBFC7D9                                            
            'gcontrollim'=cxE6F2FF                                             
            'gcerror'=cx000000                                                 
            'gerror'=cxB9CFE7                                                  
            'gcpredictlim'=cx003178                                            
            'gpredictlim'=cxB9CFE7                                             
            'gcpredict'=cx003178                                               
            'gpredict'=cx003178                                                
            'gcconfidence2'=cx003178                                           
            'gcconfidence'=cx003178                                            
            'gconfidence2'=cxB9CFE7                                            
            'gconfidence'=cxB9CFE7                                             
            'gcfit2'=cx003178                                                  
            'gcfit'=cx003178                                                   
            'gfit2'=cx003178                                                   
            'gfit'=cx003178                                                    
            'gcoutlier'=cx000000                                               
            'goutlier'=cxB9CFE7                                                
            'gcdata'=cx000000                                                  
            'gdata'=cxB9CFE7                                                   
            'ginsetheader'=colors('docbg')                                     
            'ginset'=cxFFFFFF                                                  
            'greferencelines'=cx808080                                         
            'gheader'=colors('docbg')                                          
            'gconramp3cend'=cxFF0000                                           
            'gconramp3cneutral'=cxFF00FF                                       
            'gconramp3cstart'=cx0000FF                                         
            'gramp3cend'=cxDD6475                                              
            'gramp3cneutral'=cxFFFFFF                                          
            'gramp3cstart'=cx967CD0                                            
            'gconramp2cend'=cx99CCFF                                           
            'gconramp2cstart'=cxFFFFFF                                         
            'gramp2cend'=cx967CD0                                              
            'gramp2cstart'=cxFFFFFF                                            
            'gtext'=color_list('black')                                                   
            'glabel'=color_list('black')                                                  
            'gborderlines'=color_list('black')                                            
            'goutlines'=color_list('black')                                               
            'ggrid'=cxECECEC                                                   
            'gaxis'=color_list('grey')                                                   
            'gshadow'=cx000000                                                 
            'glegend'=cxFFFFFF                                                 
            'gfloor'=cxFFFFFF                                                  
            'gwalls'=cxFFFFFF;
                                                                  
        style StartUpFunction "Controls the StartUp Function. TAGATTR is only element used.";      
        style ShutDownFunction "Controls the Shut-Down Function. TAGATTR is only element used.";    
        style Container "Abstract. Controls all container oriented elements." /              
            font=Fonts('DocFont')                                              
            color=colors('docfg')                                              
            backgroundcolor=colors('docbg');                                   
        style Index from Container "Abstract. Controls Contents and Pages." /                           
            color=colors('contentfg')                                          
            backgroundcolor=colors('contentbg');                               
        style Document from Container "Abstract. Controls the various document bodies." /                  
            doctype="<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN"">"
            contenttype="text/html"                                            
            protectspecialchars=auto;     
        style Output from Container "Abstract. Controls basic output forms." /                           
            backgroundcolor=colors('tablebg')                                  
            rules=NONE                                                         
            frame=BOX
            cellpadding=7                                                      
            borderspacing=1                                                    
            bordercollapse=separate;    
                                           
        style HeadersAndFooters from Cell "Abstract. Controls table headers and footers." /                    
            font=fonts('HeadingFont')                                          
            color=colors('headerfg')                                           
            backgroundcolor=colors('headerbg'); 
    
        style Caption from HeadersAndFooters "Abstract. Controls caption field in proc tabulate." /               
            borderspacing=0                                                    
            cellpadding=0                                                      
            color=colors('captionfg')                                          
            backgroundcolor=colors('captionbg');                                
        end;                                                                       
    run;
```

Any help will be appreciated If someone can help me figure out which ODS styles control the PROC REPORT output? So I can add borderwidth or other relevant options.
Thank You!

Comment: Show the definition of `custom_style`. Also  add some sample data and report step that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I have added the custom_style code. And the output of Report step is attached as image. This is what I am getting in the word file. No Borders.

Comment: What do you mean by "borders"?  Do you mean you are expecting visible lines on the page? I don't see any borders in your photograph.  Or do you mean the margins of the page that do not contain any content?

Comment: I mean table borders. Outside the table and between cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved finally. Turns out ODS Word doesn't work properly with custom styles. So instead used ODS RTF and used .doc instead of .docX